# How to make Google Chrome open itself at every boot?

Tags: boot, google-chrome

I want Chrome to open itself after every boot up, without entering a command or click its icon. I know there is a file, if in which you write the command or script then the command runs itself after every boot up. But I do not remember that file. 
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System Settings > Applications > Startup > Add Startup App (bottom left corner)